# how to sizeof a parameter of a function in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I have the following code in c:

```
void getNumber(int numberArray[])
{
    printf("The size of the array is %u", sizeof(numberArray));
}

void main()
{
    int array[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    getNumber(array);
}
```

but why the `The size of the array is 4`? And how to get the size of whole array?

Comment: Aren't there literally thousands of duplicates of this? Did you spend *any* time looking for similar questions?

Answer (score 3):

```
void getNumber(int numberArray[])
```

is equivalent to

```
void getNumber(int* numberArray)
```

so `sizeof(numberArray)` is just measuring the size of `int*`.

If you want to know the length of the array, you either need to pass its length as a separate argument

```
void getNumber(int* numberArray, int len)

getNumber(array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]));
```

or arrange for the array to end with a known sentinel value

```
int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,-1}; // assumes -1 is not a valid value

int arrayLength(int* numberArray)
{
    int len=0;
    while (*numberArray++ != -1) {
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, except if you're using C99 and the array is a [variable-length array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

In general an array is very much like a pointer in C, and even more so when being passed to a function.

Answer (score 0):

In case of `getnumber(array)` your array name `array` decays to pointer and is giving its size `4`. In case of `sizeof`, an array name doesn't decays to pointer and hence giving the size of entire array.